# Bukkit Plugin Messaging

Tags: java, asynchronous, wait, bukkit

I am trying to use the BungeeCord/Bukkit plugin messaging channel to receive data about players (specifically which chat channel they are in), by first sending a plugin message from Bukkit -> Bungee to request that information. 
Here's my problem. I need a way to *wait* for the response from the BungeeCord server (in the form of a plugin message), and then use it once it's recieved.

I used the tutorial [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/tutorial-advanced-plugin-messaging-spigot-bungeecord.53440/), but the server just crashes because the `onPluginMessageReceived` doesn't fire when the plugin message is recieved from the Bungee server, so `notifyAll` doesn't fire.

Here's the code for requesting the information:

```
public synchronized Object get(Player p, String... data) {
        sendToBungeeCord(p,"get",data);

        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return obj.get(p);
    }
```

And here's the code for the plugin message being recieved:

```
@Override
    public synchronized void onPluginMessageReceived(String channel, Player player, byte[] message) {
        player.sendMessage("return");
        if (channel.equals("BungeeCord")) {
            ByteArrayDataInput in = ByteStreams.newDataInput(message);
            String action = in.readUTF();
            if (action.equals("get")) {
                String dataType = in.readUTF();
                String id = in.readUTF();
                if (dataType.equals("channel")) {
                    obj.put(player,id); 
                    this.notifyAll();
                }
            } else if (action.equals("test")) {
                player.sendMessage(in.readUTF());
            }
        }
    }
```

If there is a way to do this without `wait`ing the rest of the server (the rest of the plugin can run while waiting for the response) please help me understand how I go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not block the main server thread, but instead just let it keep doing other things while you are waiting for the BungeeCord answer.

You also should **NOT** use anything async when working with this communication channel since the Spigot API is designed to work **only on the main server thread**. If you are trying to use it from other threads, then lots of bugs / side effects may appear on the server, which may even cause player data lose or even server crashes in certain situations.

So the solution to your problem would be the following:

1. Do not block the server while you are waiting for the BungeeCords answer
2. Process the result of the answer when you got it and not when you requested it